# Ubuntu не видит библиотеку для Python3 socket

Tags: python, ubuntu, сокет

Народ, в силу саморазвития занялся разработкой чата на Python. Написал код с использованием библиотеки socket и помимо теста на локальном IP захотел проверить работоспособность программы в сети, иными словами, сделать так, чтобы чатик мой был открыт пользователям. Поскольку чат делиться на клиент и сервер, я решил закинуть код сервера, который будет обрабатывать запросы клиентов,  на VDS/VPS сервер. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Библиотека socket никак не хочет устанавливаться на VDS/VPS сервер с Ubuntu. Как быть? Ошибки есть в скрине.

[image: Происходит это]

Comment: `pip` версии 8.1.1... Попробуйте обновить `pip`

Comment: Это встроенный модуль, его не нужно устанавливать